# Why is my WAMP Stack not working?

Tags: wamp

My WAMP Stack doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why.

I have Windows 7 (32-bit) installed on laptop.

I downloaded WAMP server and installed it with it's default options.

However, I noticed that Apache does not work (while MySQL does work!).

I tried to install it via Apache -> Service -> Install Service and got a message saying that port 80 is taken by Skype. I turned off Skype, and then Apache started to work.

How can I avoid this conflict and allow WAMP and Skype to work simultaneously ?

Should I configure Apache to work with other port ? Where?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option A

You have to change the port number of the WAMP server. WAMP server defaults to  port 80 upon installation. This is set in your httpd.conf file. Simply change this port number to avoid Skype conflict.

C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf

Option B

The second method is to change the port number of your Skype application.

In Skype:

Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection

Uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative".

Option C

Quit Skype before you run your WAMP server, and then you can open up Skype without any hicks. Works, but you have to do it every time.